# Meshes going berserk when extruding

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm working on a project and need to build a house. The basics of the 1st floor is done, but I have to add a foundation to it due to the landscape around the house is uneven, like on a real house.

To make the foundation, I select the bottom vertices of my outer wall on the house, and extrude them downwards, to later separate the extruded part into what will be the foundation. However, when I extrude, the mesh goes berserk, throwing and stretching faces to infinity and beyond.

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you use for this any add-on, like Archimesh or maybe boolean for doors/windows?

Comment: Only solidify..

Comment: Is this happening with Solidify turned off?

Comment: No, but when I turn it back on, the "artifacts" appear again.

Comment: It's probably because of topology, from what I see here you have there a lot of ngons. If you want me to further check it, strip down blend file and upload sample.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a topology issue. I made sure there are no duplicate faces. I have a few edges as guidelines for the doors and windows, and what you see on the GIF is a view of the entire outer wall and inner wall. I could probably work around this by applying/removing the solidifier, but I don't want to change that until it's ready for export to my game file.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in using Solidify modifier. Regardless the geometry it shouldn't jump in the viewport like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the issue.

[image]

I have two entrances to the house, a front door and a back door. To prepare for the extrude for the foundation, I added a edge below the doors, so it would make a face when extruded.

It seems that extruding non-faces is causing issues in Blender, and that's what was causing my issues.

Removing these edges before extruding works. So I can simply fill the faces after extruding.